# Error when trying to deploy shiny app to shinyapps.io (exited with code 137)

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, rsconnect

I have been trying to deploy my shiny app to shinyapps.io but I just can't seem to figure it out. Everything works fine locally but not when I try to deploy. I keep getting the following error: `The application failed to start (exited with code 137)`. I checked my logs and it says that I am out of memory.

**See below:**

[image]

All my packages get loaded and then once it comes to my data it stops and says that.. When I look at the metrics and go to the memory usage section it says I'm using less then 25 MB. My instance size is set to large (1GB). I don't understand why it's saying I'm running out of memory. I would appreciate if anybody can give me guidance or tell me something that I may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Shiny application needs resident memory. I guess because of connecting cloud service. I can't tell you one thing, but there are some things that are typically consume. R  interpreter can feel heavy and Shiny throws in another 10 MB just loading the library. I think it's helpful to you. [shiny homepage about performance](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/#performance)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already looked over that and still can't seem to figure it out